# i have a 1000 volt dc power source with milliamp current. How do i downsize my voltage to 12/18 volts without downsizing current?

Tags: voltage

I have a 1000 volt DC power source with milliamp current.   How do I downsize my voltage to 12/18 DC volts without downsizing current?

Comment: When transforming the voltage down, the current should go up, not down. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 6):

I hate to sound like a smart-mouth, but the way to do this is get 12-18 volt supply.

Since you don't want to change current, a voltage divider won't help.

Since I assume it's a DC supply, a transformer won't help either.

Most importantly, you're running something at 12-18 volts, but you are suggesting also having a live source of 1 kV right next to it. The potential for disaster (pun intended) is just enormous.

Get a cheap little supply, and don't take chances.

Answer (score 2):

Design of a SMPS that handles a 1000VDC nominal input (probably has to be good for at least 1200V) is non-trivial. The simplest approach is a flyback supply, but that stresses the switch more than some other topologies. A 600VAC-input (850VDC) can be achieved with a [1200V MOSFET](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheet/on_semiconductor/MTB3N120E-D.PDF), as seen [here](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/AN1327-D.PDF) in On Semi application note AN1327-D. SiC MOSFETs may have better characteristics but are likely not drop-in replacements.

It may be possible to stretch the above-linked design to 1000VDC (+margin) with minor changes and improving the MOSFET rating to more like [1700VDC](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/ENA1967-D.PDF). It will require some careful engineering to ensure safety and reliability.

If you're not confident enough to attempt this (may be a good call), there are board-mount modules available from several sources (probably not cheap). Just do a web search.

Comment: This might be one of the rare use-cases for vacuum tubes in modern design, too.  They are able to handle 1kv @ 80ma relatively easily.

Comment: @BryanBoettcher Bootstrapping the filament supply might be an interesting challenge.

Comment: he just needs a 1kv-to-12v power supply to run the filament! ;)